# BitmapImage not loading from resources in WPF 4.5

Tags: wpf, uri, bitmapimage

I am building a dynamic list of WPF MenuItem on WPF 4.5 on Windows 7.
Building them and getting them to display a title is working fine.
But I am not able to get them to load icons. I have found a few posts on the topic but none of them is solving the problem.
The property the MenuItem Icon is bound to is defined the following way in my latest attempt. But I have tried all combinations of relative URI, path, etc.

```
    public override Image MenuIcon
    {
        get
        {
            Image i = new Image();
            BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
            src.BeginInit();
            src.UriSource = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/" 
                    + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name 
                    + ";Images/bold.png", UriKind.Absolute); 
            src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            src.EndInit();
            i.Source = src;
            return i;
        }
    }
```

I get an exception saying that the file cannot be found...
The bold.png file is in the Images folder and has the 'Resource' Build Action.

Comment: I should have added that the bold.png file in the Images folder has a 'Resource' build action so is included.

Comment: Why this complicated way to create a pack URI? How about `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/bold.png")`?

Comment: Well I had tried that before but my icon was not showing...I tried again and it is still not showing. When debugging I see the following on the Metadata property of Source: Metadata '(i.Source).Metadata' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' System.Windows.Media.ImageMetadata {System.NotSupportedException}.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed! The issue is, I was binding to the Icon property of a MenuItem type, instead of binding the ImageSource of a RibbonMenuItem!

Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure if you need a relative or an absolute URI (different APIs prefer one or the other), but here are both of them:

```
// These two work regardless which loaded assembly the image is in, so long as you
// replace the assembly name with the name of the assembly containing the image.

// Absolute
new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ";component/Images/bold.png", UriKind.Absolute);

// Relative
new Uri("/" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + ";component/Images/bold.png", UriKind.Relative);


// These two should also work if in local assembly (only works from within main
// executing assembly, not from within loaded DLLs).

// Absolute
new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/bold.png", UriKind.Absolute);

// Relative
new Uri("Images/bold.png", UriKind.Relative);
```

It looks like you are just missing the "component" part of the path to make it match the first example.

See [Pack URIs in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Absolute URI and local assembly do not work, that is the image is not displayed. Relative Uri throws an exception ...

Comment: If the Uri is valid (no exception is thrown when you call src.EndInit()), then the issue may be occurring later on in the code flow. I don't know how you are building your view, but in isolation it looks a bit unusual to have a method that returns a new Image rather than a method that returns an ImageSource which later is assigned to an existing Image. Where you end up eventually placing that image in the visual tree can affect how it lays out and eventually renders the image. More information about how the Image is used could help track down the issue.